# Asset Pipeline Not Compiling On Local Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I just upgraded to Rails 3.1 and I'm having an issue with the Asset Pipeline. Basically when I'm doing local dev and I make a change to any of my .css.scss files I have to run:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

On the command line and THEN refresh the browser before I can see any style changes. How can I make it so that it automatically precompiles every time I reload the page in development?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the last section of the [assets pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#upgrading-from-old-versions-of-rails), and make sure that the settings you have in your upgraded app's config files match those in the guide.

Delete the files you have in public/assets and you should be good from there.